# VueJS keep the same dependencies version in different branches on update

Tags: git, vue.js

I don't understand how I can keep the same dependencies version in my package.json when I update all my dependencies by running `npm update` on different branches.

E.g I have 3 branches: `dev` `staging` `prod`

If today I run `npm update` on the `dev` branch and tomorrow I run `npm update` on the `staging` branch I can get a diff for certain packages e.g vuetify version 2.5.0 in `dev` and 2.5.1 in `staging`.

What is the best way to get the same version in all branches when I run an update on a certain branch ?

Comment: how does your `package.json` look like? do you got a prefix on a version number like: `~` or `^`?

Comment: I have `^` everywhere

Comment: than you should read about the difference and effects what the caret is gonna do. [Hope it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json). ps. remove the `^` and you got a fixed version.

Comment: @wittgenstein Okay thank you for your answer. So in my production package.json I can remove all `^`  and I can let the `^` in dev, and when I merge new features in production I set the new dependencies version manuallyif needed